# Get the Count of Concatenating Column in sql

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, model-view-controller

i have Concatenating the multiple Columns and i want the count of how many columns are Concatenated

the query output and expected output are

for Concatenation

```
select  ConcateColumn = STUFF(
                              COALESCE('* ' + RTRIM(col1),'') 
                             +COALESCE('* ' + RTRIM(col2),'') 
                             +COALESCE('* ' + RTRIM(col4),'') 
                             +COALESCE('* ' + RTRIM(col3),'') 
                       , 1, 2, '')
```

table

```
===================================
| col1   | col2  |  col3  |  col4 | 
===================================
|  1     | 2     |  NULL  | NULL  |
|  NULL  | NULL  |  NULL  | NULL  |
|  1     | NULL  |  NULL  | NULL  |
|  NULL  | 2     |  3     | 4     |
|        | NULL  |  NULL  | NULL  |       
==================================
```

the resulted output

```
 ==============
|ConcateColumn|
 ==============
|1*2          |
|NULL         |
|1            |
|2*3*4        |
|             |
===============
```

Expected Output

```
------------------------
| Count | ConcateColumn |
-------------------------
|   2   |     1*2       |
|   0   |     NULL      |
|   1   |     1         |
|   3   |     2*3*4     |
|   0   |               |
-------------------------
```

if i get the count that is more than enough

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could do something using `CASE` statements and a subquery to achieve this.  What have you already tried to calculate this?

Comment: please note that the no of  columns are dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of `*` in the concatenated string:

```
with cte as 
 (
   select  
      ConcateColumn = STUFF(  COALESCE('* ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(col1),''),'') 
                             +COALESCE('* ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(col2),''),'') 
                             +COALESCE('* ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(col3),''),'') 
                             +COALESCE('* ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(col4),''),'') 
                       , 1, 2, '') 
   FROM T
 )
select ConcateColumn,
   -- how many '*' have been removed?
   coalesce(len(ConcateColumn) - len(replace(ConcateColumn, '*', '')) + 1, 0)
from cte 
;
```

Of course, this will return wrong numbers if your data contains `*`

Comment: if the column is empty i need count as 0 , but im getting as 1

Comment: What do you mean by *empty*? Empty string `''`? It works with the D-Shih's https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=df4ea6b933bb8c70805880832aad1566

Comment: check it in fiddle in last insert column

Comment: INSERT INTO T VALUES ( NULL, ''  ,  NULL  , NULL  );

Comment: Well, an empty string is not the same as a NULL, of course it's counted.

Comment: but i  want  as 0. tats y i specified in my question clearly.

Comment: Well, you didn't specify it clearly, e.g. if you got an empty string as `col4` in the first row your query would return `1*2*  `

Comment: but i specified in 5 th row      => |   0   |               |

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
select  (SELECT count(NULLIF(val,''))
        FROM   (VALUES(col1),(col2),(col3), (col4)) v (val)) 'COUNT',
          ConcateColumn = STUFF(
                              COALESCE('* ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(col1),''),'') 
                             +COALESCE('* ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(col2),''),'') 
                             +COALESCE('* ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(col3),''),'') 
                             +COALESCE('* ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(col4),''),'') 
                       , 1, 2, '')
FROM T
```

If you want to count without `NULL` and `''` you can try to use `NULLIF` function.

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e380a7e10ecb7353cacc795eebf955e8)

Comment: `count` instead of `sum`, but you beat me to it... +1 :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes Thanks

Comment: please note that the columns may a string, just for understanding i gave it as numbers

Comment: @RamapriyanC It can work if columns are string https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4f11f4cdcb4a2d866374613a2ff16221

Comment: @D-shih if i give empty column  it shows count as 1

Comment: @RamapriyanC but your expect result show us is  `0`... could you edit your question?

Comment: @RamapriyanC Is that your expect https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=486d08122162b6b2da1e2cea56aa03e4?

Comment: 5th row should come as 0 not count as 1

Comment: If you want empty strings treated as NULLs, you must add `NULLIF`, e.g. `RTRIM(NULLIF(col1),''))

Comment: and if any one of the column is int i shd not get the error

Comment: First  `NULL` <> `''` and if you want to do that you can use `NULLIF` function to make you expect  as dnoeth say @RamapriyanC

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2017+, you can simply do:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt,
             string_agg(rtrim(col), '* ') within group (order by ord) as ConcateColumn
      from (values (1, col1), (2, col2), (3, col4), (4, col3)
           ) v(col, ord)
      where col is not null
     ) v;
```

In earlier versions, I would probably follow the same structure that you have:

```
select ( (case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col4 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select sum(
case when col1 = '' then 0 when col1 is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when col2 = '' then 0 when col2 is null then 0 else 1 end + 
case when col3 = '' then 0 when col3 is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when col4 = '' then 0 when col4 is null then 0 else 1 end ) 'COUNT',
      ConcateColumn = STUFF(
                          COALESCE('* ' + RTRIM(col1),'') 
                         +COALESCE('* ' + RTRIM(col2),'') 
                         +COALESCE('* ' + RTRIM(col4),'') 
                         +COALESCE('* ' + RTRIM(col3),'') 
                   , 1, 2, '') from temp1
                   group by col1,col2,col3,col4
```